# Accessing user properties in External network using Rest API

Tags: yammer

Does anybody know how user profiles are managed in external networks ? In particular, when we get Users using the REST API, Yammer respond with a user data where:

- The user id in the external network is not the same as the user id in the principal network
- Email address is replaced by something like username+externalnetwork@users.yammer.com"

Do you know if there is a way to find the user principal properties by requesting the external nerwork (or maybe find a way to match the user between its principal and external networks) ?

By the way is there any documentation somewhere about the External Networks and the REST API ?

Answer (score 0):

User profiles in external networks are separate in that they have different user IDs and state (pending, active, deleted etc.) To avoid duplication you only edit name, job title etc. in the home network and that appears in the other profiles. This explains why the users have different IDs.

When you get a user profile for /domain.com/api/v1/users/current.json and /en-pemalink/api/v1/users/current.json you should get different results back. I don't know if there is a recommended way because this isn't documented, or generally recommended for third parties. Zapier published some information on the [quirks](https://zapier.com/blog/api-quirks-yammer-external-networks/) of the API that may be helpful.

Comment: I recently noticed that all the user profiles have the same _email_ and _name_ properties.
Do you know if we can use those properties as some kind of unique keys, ie if two user profiles have the same _name_ property, that means that they are linked to a single "physical user" account ?